# Server computer died and the repositories were lost, how to recover?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I had a server that I linked to my current PC as "Z:\", and I had a repository there that I used for my programming commit/updates. There were multiple people working on the program, which warranted the need for a repository. We worked with Visual Studio and VisualSVN.

Unfortunately, my server died and we couldn't get it to start back up, so we've lost the repository. I have since bought and replaced my old server with a new one, but I'm having trouble re-creating the repository. For argument's sake, let's say that the copy of the program on my PC is the most updated one. How do I re-create the repository so that everyone can update/commit from there again?

Answer (score 0):

1. In case there are multiple users who need access your repository, you should use a server, not direct file access schema (`file://`).
2. You must plan a backup strategy for your server and the repositories.

If you lost the storage that was holding the repositories, you lost the revision history of your projects. However, you should have the local copies of the project's data on your computers in form of working copies.

Search for working copies of your projects. The working copies will help you recover the latest state of your data and import it to a new SVN repository. Make sure that you do not import the hidden `.svn` metadata directory.

Comment: Is there a way to not import it, or do I have to manually search for the .svn metadata in every folder and delete it?

Comment: @Wakka02 https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-unversion-wc.html